# useState is freezing the render flow in useFrame using react-three-fiber

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm moving a project that I had in three js to react-three-fiber and I'm having some problems with the render loop. Maybe I don't entirely understand how useFrame works.

Here is the CodeSandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-three-test-y0zrx?file=/src/Three.jsx:1824-1835

So in this project I'm using the scroll to move the camera on the z-axis and change the year displayed when we reach different points on the z position. As you can see when we reach this points we use a useState set function that changes the state but also creates a lag and inactivates the render effects for a moment.

This is the renderer function that changes the displayed information (year from the position):

**ThreeComponent.jsx**

```
const getYear = cameraZ => parseInt(cameraZ / -10 + START_YEAR, 10);
const getRoundedYear = year => Math.round(year / 10) * 10;

const shouldDisplayYear = roundedYear => {
    return (
      roundedYear % 100 === 0 || (roundedYear > 1890 && roundedYear % 10 === 0)
    );
  };

  function Renderer() {
    const composer = useRef();
    const { scene, gl, camera } = useThree();
    useFrame(() => {
      const roundedYear = getRoundedYear(getYear(camera.position.z));
      if (shouldDisplayYear(roundedYear)) {

        // The problem lies here
        setDisplayedYear(roundedYear);
      }
      return composer?.current?.render();
    }, 1);
    return (
      <effectComposer ref={composer} args={[gl]}>
        <renderPass attachArray="passes" scene={scene} camera={camera} />
        <bokehPass
          attachArray="passes"
          args={[
            scene,
            camera,
            {
              focus: 20.0,
              aperture: 1.1 * 0.00008,
              maxblur: 0.05,
              width: window.innerWidth,
              height: window.innerHeight
            }
          ]}
        />
      </effectComposer>
    );
  }
  ...
  return (
    <div className="three-component" ref={canvasRef}>
      <Canvas
       ...>
       ...
       <Renderer/>
      </Canvas>
     </div>
  );
```

The set function is passed from the parent component but it has the same problem if its on the same component:

**ThreeComponent.jsx**

```
const ThreeComponent = ({ setDisplayedYear, startYear }) => {
```

**App.js (Parent)**

```
  const [displayedYear, setDisplayedYear] = useState(START_YEAR);
```

Could someone shed some light on why this lag is happening? Or maybe having a better way to move the camera only with scroll and updating the number.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

useFrame is a render-loop, it's running 60 times per second, you can't have side-effects in there. setDisplayedYear will ask react to do all its heavy lifting, diffing, going through vdoms, etc. at best it will tank performance, or it will just kill the tab.

there are many things you can do here, best would be to mutate the camera right then and there. you get it from useState(state => state.camera. i would remove all the setState stuff.

edit:

i think you're also re-creating lots of objects in there needlessly on every render. function Renderer() for instance is created every time the setState changes, it's re-creating the entire effects stuff from scratch. components should always be fixed references.

here's an example that dollying the camera in and out: https://codesandbox.io/s/r3f-lod-rzuj1

here's another that's probably closer to what you need (cam reacting to scroll offset): https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-feather-nk16u